# Rotating all the views of a TabBarController

Tags: iphone

I have a TabBarController app with 4 views.
I've put on all the 4 viewControllers the autorotate method returning yes :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks to this, now when i rotate the iPhone the rotation works, and even the TabBar is rotated.

In every single view i can use the following code to update to view when the rotation occurs:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

//Here i can update the view when it goes to landscape

    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
             orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

//Here i can update the view when it goes to portrait

    }

}
```

**The problem is that when i make the rotation, only the current displayed view is updating. If later i change view clicking on the tabBar, i see the view not updated for the new orientation.**

Is there a way to make all the views being aware of the orientation changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it! =D

The trick is using the function:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Just call it in your viewControllers, and insert inside the code to update the view. Enjoy!

Comment: I must wait till tomorrow to do it!

Comment: I suspect that this only happened for views you had already visited, but not for those you visited for the first time.